# Socket.IO initial packet

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, network-protocols

I am implementing websocket v07 server protocol in C/C++. It's pretty easy and I have almost coded it. Though I can't understand what mean numbers in first initial packet (not handshake)? Client uses "socket.io" framework. So client sends Date and server answer with another number. I think its something like checksum. Can anyone explain me please how to generate answer and what does it mean?

Examples:

```
client GET./socket.io/1/?t=1322647367092&jsonp=0

server 52 io.j[0]("1880965230667822746 :15:25:websocket,htmlfile,xhr-polling,jsonp-polling");

client GET./socket.io/1/?t=1322647141334&jsonp=0

server 52 io.j[0]("7826289221657265491 :15:25:websocket,htmlfile,xhr-polling,jsonp-polling");
```

`1322647367092` - Date, server answer - `1880965230667822746`

`1322647141334` - Date, server answer - `7826289221657265491`

My Packet ->

```
000000 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 | 20 32 30 30 20 4F 4B 0D     HTTP/1.1.200.OK.
000010 0A 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 | 2D 54 79 70 65 3A 20 61     .Content-Type:.a
000020 70 70 6C 69 63 61 74 69 | 6F 6E 2F 6A 61 76 61 73     pplication/javas
000030 63 72 69 70 74 0D 0A 43 | 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 69 6F     cript..Connectio
000040 6E 3A 20 6B 65 65 70 2D | 61 6C 69 76 65 0D 0A 54     n:.keep-alive..T
000050 72 61 6E 73 66 65 72 2D | 45 6E 63 6F 64 69 6E 67     ransfer-Encoding
000060 3A 20 63 68 75 6E 6B 65 | 64 0D 0A 0D 0A 35 30 0D     :.chunked....50.
000070 0A 69 6F 2E 6A 5B 30 5D | 28 22 32 37 38 38 39 39     .io.j[0]("278899
000080 38 30 38 38 32 36 32 34 | 38 38 30 3A 31 35 3A 32     80882624880:15:2
000090 35 3A 77 65 62 73 6F 63 | 6B 65 74 2C 68 74 6D 6C     5:websocket,html
0000A0 66 69 6C 65 2C 78 68 72 | 2D 70 6F 6C 6C 69 6E 67     file,xhr-polling
0000B0 2C 6A 73 6F 6E 70 2D 70 | 6F 6C 6C 69 6E 67 22 29     ,jsonp-polling")
0000C0 3B 0D 0A 30 0D 0A 0D 0A                               ;..0....
```

Original Packet ->

```
000000 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 | 20 32 30 30 20 4F 4B 0D     HTTP/1.1.200.OK.
000010 0A 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 | 2D 54 79 70 65 3A 20 61     .Content-Type:.a
000020 70 70 6C 69 63 61 74 69 | 6F 6E 2F 6A 61 76 61 73     pplication/javas
000030 63 72 69 70 74 0D 0A 43 | 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 69 6F     cript..Connectio
000040 6E 3A 20 6B 65 65 70 2D | 61 6C 69 76 65 0D 0A 54     n:.keep-alive..T
000050 72 61 6E 73 66 65 72 2D | 45 6E 63 6F 64 69 6E 67     ransfer-Encoding
000060 3A 20 63 68 75 6E 6B 65 | 64 0D 0A 0D 0A 35 30 0D     :.chunked....50.
000070 0A 69 6F 2E 6A 5B 30 5D | 28 22 33 38 34 35 36 31     .io.j[0]("384561
000080 33 32 31 33 36 32 32 39 | 34 30 37 3A 31 35 3A 32     32136229407:15:2
000090 35 3A 77 65 62 73 6F 63 | 6B 65 74 2C 68 74 6D 6C     5:websocket,html
0000A0 66 69 6C 65 2C 78 68 72 | 2D 70 6F 6C 6C 69 6E 67     file,xhr-polling
0000B0 2C 6A 73 6F 6E 70 2D 70 | 6F 6C 6C 69 6E 67 22 29     ,jsonp-polling")
0000C0 3B 0D 0A 30 0D 0A 0D 0A                               ;..0....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a "session ID" according to the [socket.io protocol specification](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io-spec):

> The body of the response should contain the session id (`sid`) given to the client, followed by the heartbeat timeout, the connection closing timeout, and the list of supported transports separated by `:`

Comment: @user1077948: I don't know for sure; I did some research and it is generated here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/manager.js#L689.

Comment: return Math.abs(Math.random() * Math.random() * Date.now() | 0).toString() + Math.abs(Math.random() * Math.random() * Date.now() | 0).toString();
}; Something like this in c?                                     time = _atoi64("1322647141334");
   _i64toa(abs((INT64)((rand()/(FLOAT)RAND_MAX) * (rand()/(FLOAT)RAND_MAX) * time)), t1, 10);
   _i64toa(abs((INT64)((rand()/(FLOAT)RAND_MAX) * (rand()/(FLOAT)RAND_MAX) * time)), t2, 10);
   strcat(t1, t2);                               Length is bigger than in original. Sorry iam not good at js.

Comment: @user1077948: I don't know C, but `| 0` rounds a number down to the nearest integer, but `abs` I don't know - the multiplication should always have a positive result anyway. Perhaps to make really sure the ID does not contain minus signs.

Comment: _i64toa(abs(floor((rand()/(FLOAT)RAND_MAX) * (rand()/(FLOAT)RAND_MAX) * time)), t1, 10);
_i64toa(abs(floor((rand()/(FLOAT)RAND_MAX) * (rand()/(FLOAT)RAND_MAX) * time)), t2, 10); So it should look like this i think. Anyway my number is 24 length and in original packet 19 length. whats can be wrong?

Comment: @user1077948: Not sure if that matters; with the JavaScript code I sometimes get a length of 19 and other times a length of 20.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made test js script and length is 15~20. And In C realization is 16~18. Anyway socket.io handshake doesnt work properly. Client continues sending GET requests. Someone have idea whats wrong?

Comment: Add packets in first question.